# USB 3.0 external hard disk only operating at 480 Mbit/s

Tags: usb, performance

When I attach my USB 3.0-Stick `dmesg` says:

```
[ 3308.966755] usb 2-1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 3308.987443] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[ 3308.987444] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3308.987445] usb 2-1.1: Product: Ultra Fit
[ 3308.987446] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 3308.987447] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 4C530001130125108084
[ 3308.987973] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3308.988102] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[ 3310.003801] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3310.004113] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] 60062500 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[ 3310.004332] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 3310.004725] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[ 3310.004727] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3310.004993] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3310.011636]  sde:
[ 3310.012638] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3337.899311] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 3337.916315] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3338.164228] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3345.232408] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

But when I connect my USB 3.0 hard drive to the same port `dmesg` says:

```
[ 3354.269053] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 3354.449932] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0579
[ 3354.449936] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3354.449939] usb 1-1.1: Product: External USB-3.0
[ 3354.449941] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Intenso
[ 3354.449943] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 2015112320089
[ 3354.451081] scsi host6: uas
[ 3354.451512] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  External USB-3.0 1201 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3354.452039] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 3357.101531] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 3357.101533] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 3357.101709] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 3357.101710] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 5f 00 00 08
[ 3357.101963] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3357.108787]  sdc: sdc1
[ 3357.110080] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 3411.218491] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 3411.236156] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3411.488046] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

My `dd`-benchmark confirms USB 2.0 speed:

```
user@host:~> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/largefile bs=8k count=2000000
dd: error writing '/mnt/largefile': File too large
524288+0 records in
524287+0 records out
4294967295 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 54.0439 s, 79.5 MB/s
user@host:~> sudo sh -c "sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
[sudo] password for root: 
user@host:~> dd if=/mnt/largefile of=/dev/null bs=8k
524287+1 records in
524287+1 records out
4294967295 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 101.613 s, 42.3 MB/s
```

While `lsusb -v` confirms "super speed capability"

```
user@host:~> sudo lsusb -v -D /dev/bus/usb/001/018
Device: ID 152d:0579 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x0579 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Intenso
  iProduct                2 External USB-3.0
  iSerial                 3 2015112320089
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000f0e
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
    BESL value     3840 us 
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat          32 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

This is the output of `lsusb -t` with the USB-Stick:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

And this is `lsusb -t` with the hard drive connected *to the same port*:

```
    sudo lsusb -t -D /dev/bus/usb/001/018
    /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
    /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 8: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

*How can I make this device operate at USB 3.0 **SuperSpeed?***

Comment: Errr.... have you tried a different USB cable? USB 3 runs over different pins & wires than USB 2. (So a USB-3 cable actually has *two* sets of pins & wires, ones for USB 2 and one for USB 3. Were the USB 3 ones to be damaged, you'd potentially get USB 2)

Comment: Statistics are statistics at the end of the day...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Short version:**

Your [Intenso external SSD](https://www.intenso.de/produkte/solid-state-drives) is already performing at peak performance if you bought the High performance model.  However, if you bought the Top performance model, you should:

1. try another USB3.1 cable first
2. contact the manufacturer after you've ruled out cabling problems.

**The long version:**

1. All USB cables are equal, but some are more equal than others:

   **USB 2.0 layout:**

   ```
   Pin     Colour      Name    Description
   1       Red         VCC     +5 VDC
   2       White       D-      Data -
   3       Green       D+      Data +
   4       Black       GND     Ground
   ```

   **USB 3.x layout:**

   ```
   Pin     Colour              Name                Description
                   A connector     B connector
   1   Red                     VBUS                Power
   2   White                   D−                  USB 2.0 differential pair
   3   Green                   D+
   4   Black                   GND                 Ground for power return
   5   Blue        StdA_SSRX−      StdB_SSTX−      SuperSpeed receiver differential pair
   6   Yellow      StdA_SSRX+      StdB_SSTX+
   7   N/A                     GND_DRAIN           Ground for signal return
   8   Purple      StdA_SSTX−      StdB_SSRX−      SuperSpeed transmitter differential pair
   9   Orange      StdA_SSTX+      StdB_SSRX+
   ```

   So if you have a damaged cable or have the wrong cable, you should replace it or you'll fall back to USB 2.0.
2. The two main parts of a SSD are the controller bridge and the actual [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_Flash) chips.  In your case, the [JMicron Controller Bridge](http://www.jmicron.com/product02.html) is *capable* of **SuperSpeed**, but the actual NAND in your SSD is *only capable of **High-Speed** as your tests confirmed*.

   What's the difference between SuperSpeed and High-speed NAND?

   - [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell): 1 bit per cell: *fastest, highest cost.*
   - [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Multi-level_cell): 2 bits per cell
   - [TLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Triple-level_cell): 3 bits per cell
   - [QLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Quad-level_cell): 4 bits per cell: *slowest, lowest cost*

   So your (small) USB Stick contains both SuperSpeed-capable controller and NAND but your (large) SSD only contains the SuperSpeed-capable controller but not the NAND that goes with it.

   As you gave us a lot of information, but not the actual model number of the SSD, we cannot check whether you bought the High performance instead of the Top performance model as Intenso does not publish the USB ID on their web site. Generally, the Top Performance is twice as expensive as the High-performance model, so *in the unlikely case* you did buy the Top Performance model, there was a mix-up at the manufacturer and you should contact them and ask for a replacement.

Comment: Loads of information? The post does not even mention the brand of the machine.

Comment: The question says that the harddisk shows up as an USB 2  device instead of an USB 3 device (the most probable reason is bad cabling). That is totally independent of the speed of the NAND chips; even if the NAND chips are really slow, USB transfer should still be able to function at USB 3 speeds (and thus leave bandwidth for other devices on the same bus).

Comment: @dirkt Edited to include more information on cabling in the long version as well.

Comment: Oh my god! Yes, thank you. It is the cable! I just used a USB 2.0 cable (with USB 2.0 Micro B plug). Oops, sorry for the blind spot!

Comment: Geez. I never would have thought to try a different cable until I read your comment! "All USB cables are equal, but some are more equal than others" indeed.